# Can “vice versa” be used with exclusion?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, logic

Normally, the phrase appears as either a conjunction or disjunction of a proposition with its swapped form:

> Alice is good enough at chess to play exciting games against Bob, and vice versa.

> Let's save some fuel, I can pick you up with my car. Or vice versa.

But it's also conceivable to use it with one side negated

> A bulldozer is able to push a bicycle off the road, but not vice versa.

> I don't like eating savoury things like cheese after dessert, only vice versa.

This seems to be less common though. Would these combinations still be generally accepted and understood, or are they eschewed for some reason?

Wiktionary notes that *vice versa* [specifically “is preceded by *and* or *or*”](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=vice_versa&oldid=71889492#Usage_notes). On the other hand, quotes where it's preceded by *not* or *only* can be readily found on the internet – but that's not necessarily an indication that it's a sound construct one should use in reasonably formal writing. (Especially for terms adapted from a language like Latin, which are particularly prone to hyperforeignism.)

Of course it would be possible to use “the other way around” instead, but that is rather less elegant.

Comment: You can find many examples of both ["not vice versa"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22not+vice+versa%22) and ["only vice versa"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22only+vice+versa%22) in Google Books.

Comment: Why not show us some research?

Comment: For you final example *(I don't like eating **savoury** things like cheese **after** dessert, only vice versa)* it's not clear to me whether "vice-versa" means *I [do] like eating **sweet** things [like cake] **after** dessert* OR *I [do] like eating **savoury** things [like cheese] **before** dessert*. BTW - I don't share your belief that ***the other way around*** is "less elegant" than ***vice-versa***.